# Отобразить коллекцию в элементе управления TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется некая коллекция `ICollection<OperandItemVM> Operands`

`OperandItemVM` выглядит вот так:

```
public class OperandItemVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      public string OperandName { get; set; }
      public string Value{ get; set; }
      public string Path{ get; set; }

   }
```

Не получается отобразить эту информацию вот в таком виде (одноуровневое дерево):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сейчас пробую вот так, но значок раскрытия не отображается:

```
<TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Operands}">
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:OperandItemVM}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MinHeight="25">
           <TextBox Text="{Binding OperandName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
           <Button Width="19" Height="19" Margin="15,0,0,0">
              <TextBlock Text="X" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
           </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:OperandItemVM}">
              <Grid Margin="3">
                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="23"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="23"/>
                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="91"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" MinWidth="101"/>
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                 <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Значение"/>
                 <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                 </Border>

                 <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Путь"/>
                 <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}"/>
                 </Border>
              </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FrozDark** дал полезный ответ, но всё же я сначала искал решение для TreeView. Оно получилось немного костыльное, имхо, но пока сбоя не дало.

В `ViewModel` я создал коллекцию, которая хранит только один объект (саму `ViewModel`).

Поясню: имеется `UserControl`, у которого в ресурсах определены два `HierarchicalDataTemplate`

```
<UserControl x:Class="ExpressionsEditor.View.OperandsList"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExpressionsEditor"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ExpressionsEditor.ViewModel"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:ExpressionsEditor.Model"
             xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:ExpressionsEditor.View"
             xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:ExpressionsEditor.Converters"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
   <UserControl.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
         <conv:IsNodeConverter x:Key="IsNodeConverter"/>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SecondLevel" DataType="{x:Type model:OperandItemModel}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,5">
               <view:PSRMeas/>
            </StackPanel>
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="FirstLevel"
                                   DataType="{x:Type model:OperandItemModel}"
                                   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SecondLevel}"
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentItem}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
               <TextBox Text="{Binding OperandName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextChanged="tb_TextChanged" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

               <Button Width="21" Height="21" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                  <TextBlock Text="X" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
               </Button>
            </StackPanel>
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </ResourceDictionary>
   </UserControl.Resources>
   <TreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=FirstLevel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Operands}" x:Name="operandsList" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,5,0,0">

   </TreeView>
</UserControl>
```

В первый уровень я передаю коллекцию вида:

```
public ICollection<OperandItemModel> Operands
```

А в `OperandItemModel` содержится коллекция `public ObservableCollection<OperandItemModel> CurrentItem`, которая хранит один объект `OperandItemModel`. Эта коллекция передаётся во второй уровень. Т.о. достигается нужный результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

> Если это одноуровневое дерево, то попробуй использовать вместо
>   HierarchicalDataTemplate сам DataTemplate. Не могу писать пока в
>   комментариях, буду писать в ответах

Ответ выше не годится

В вашем случае лучше использовать ListView, TreeView не годится для ваших целей

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding Operands}>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander Header="{Binding OperandName}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='Значение - {0}'}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path, StringFormat='Путь - {0}'}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: а как переопределить и содержимое и Header?

Comment: @alladuh, изначально не понял суть вопроса. Исправил ответ

Comment: TreeView не годится или его просто невозможно использовать?

Comment: @alladuh, использовать можно, но будет примерно так же, как и ListView. Можете попробовать вместо ListView, подставить TreeView, выглядеть будут одинаково. TreeView все таки дерево, где можно отобразить множество веток. Чтоб в вашем случае TreeView работал как следует, нужно перенести свойства Value и Path в отдельный класс, и в OperandItemVM добавить этот класс, затем в HierarchicalDataTemplate указать в свойство ItemsSource этот самый класс и уже в ItemTemplate установить дизайн. В комменте не удобно описать код, поэтому если нужно, могу другим ответом приложить что я имел ввиду подробнее

Comment: @alladuh, объясните, зачем вам именно TreeView?

Comment: Вообще это некое тз. Возможно я смогу использовать что-то другое, но сначала хотелось реализовать требование. Я нашёл решение, но это больше костыль: в `OperandItemVM` добавил новое свойство `public ObservableCollection<OperandItemVM> CurrentItem` , которое содержит только один текущий item и его передаю в ItemSource второго  `HierarchicalDataTemplate`